# EF6.1.3 Expects CreatedOn field in __MigrationHistory table when upgrading in VS2015 IDE

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, xaf

in program.cs I have

```
private static bool CheckMigrationVersionAndUpgradeIfNeeded()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new jtDbContext())
            {
                if (db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return RunMigrations(db);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var s = string.Format("Problem in MigrateIfNeeded /n/p" + ex);
            MessageBox.Show(s);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static bool RunMigrations(jtDbContext db)
    { 
            if (!AskForPassword()) { return false}
            return db.RunMigrations();
     }
```

in my context i have

```
    public void RunMigrations()
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
        var pendings = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();
        foreach (var pending in pendings)
        {
            migrator.Update(pending);
        }
    }
```

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979026/entity-framework-5-expects-createdon-column-from-migrationhistory-table) that there was an issue in EF5 relating to this field.

I am using DevExpress Xaf in the project but I cant see how this could be relevant.

I can still run the migration by typing update-database at the PM> prompt

I can work around the problem by running the following script prior to updating

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.__MigrationHistory ADD CreatedOn DateTime Default GETDATE()
GO
UPDATE dbo.__MigrationHistory SET CreatedOn = GETDATE()
```

[Update] The problem happens when running within the VS2015 Update1 IDE. It does not happen when I run the .exe

Comment: Maybe the issue simply hasn't been fixed for EF6. Does that make this question a duplicate?  Since it has the same work around as the EF5 issue I have linked.

Comment: The above was running in the IDE.